# PHP DateTime Diff DST

Tags: php, datetime, dst

My problem is with this code

```
$d1 = new DateTime('2016-02-29', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$d2 = new DateTime('1998-03-01', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $d1->diff($d2)->y;
```

Could you be so kind to execute this command in your machine?

```
php -r "\$d1 = new DateTime('2016-02-29', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));\$d2 = new DateTime('1998-03-01', new DateTimeZone('UTC')); echo \$d1->diff(\$d2)->y;"
```

This returns `18` in my machine, but it have passed 17 years, not 18.

I can't understand why, and in this php online interpreter 
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/50cc70c56695f08c62047fb7841aae9fec4c2ec6

It says `17`!

My php.ini has

```
php -i | grep timezone
Default timezone => Europe/Madrid
date.timezone => Europe/Madrid => Europe/Madrid
```

But if I change to 'UTC' It keeps failing and saying 18 years.

Also It doesn't matter as I'm setting the timezone to UTC in the code to avoid DST.

What's going on?!

**EDIT:**

```
php -r "\$d1 = new DateTime('2016-02-29T00:00:00Z');\$d2 = new DateTime('1998-03-01T00:00:00Z'); echo \$d1->diff(\$d2)->y;"
```

This gives me `17`

It seems that DateTime thinks that the input comes as non-UTC timezone and it does weird internal stuff from there.

Comment: No repro https://3v4l.org/KGOFg on any version

Comment: I ran it using the current versions of PHP 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6 and 7.0. All of them displayed `17`. Homebrew PHP on OSX El Capitan.

Comment: aha, so, i thing, this is a PHP bug in work with datetime (if february have a 29 days). As example: please diff with 1998-03-01 to 2015-02-29 and 2016-02-29. The first and second time will return 17 year :D

Comment: https://3v4l.org/BXLlk why why why

Answer (score 0):

Both dates represent the same - 59th - day of the year:

```
$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', '01.03.1998')->format('z'));
string(2) "59"
php > var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', '29.02.2016')->format('z'));
string(2) "59"
```

Not to say that you are incorrect, but it is also perfectly valid to say that 18 years have passed between the 59th day of 1998 and the 59th day of 2016.

If I had to guess, PHP calculates the difference exactly that way in this particular scenario and this is obviously an edge case, so we just have to accept the paradox.